# Unknown source on BIRT report

Tags: mysql, birt

I've been trying for quite some time to run this report out of the server. We use Tomcat. The report runs fine in Eclipse designed, but once I upload it to the server and run in, it gives the following unknown source errors.

I'm using mysql.

Thanks for your help

```
The following items have errors: 


TextData (id = 912): 
- Can not load the report query: 912. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 912. 
Error.ReportQueryLoadingError2 ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Can not load the report query: 912. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 912.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataPresentationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataPresentationEngine.java:164)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1890)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.executeQuery(ReportItemExecutor.java:412)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.DynamicTextItemExecutor.doExecute(DynamicTextItemExecutor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.execute(ReportItemExecutor.java:294)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.prepareChildExecutor(ContainerExecutor.java:226)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.hasNextChild(ContainerExecutor.java:110)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:661)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:284)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1545)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.doRenderPage(BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.java:82)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.__execute(AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.java:103)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleChangeParameter(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:100)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



Table (id = 603): 
- Can not load the report query: 603. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 603. 
Error.ReportQueryLoadingError2 ( 1 time(s) )
detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Can not load the report query: 603. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 603.
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataPresentationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataPresentationEngine.java:164)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1890)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.executeQuery(ReportItemExecutor.java:412)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.TableItemExecutor.doExecute(TableItemExecutor.java:72)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ReportItemExecutor.execute(ReportItemExecutor.java:294)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.prepareChildExecutor(ContainerExecutor.java:226)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.document.v4.ContainerExecutor.hasNextChild(ContainerExecutor.java:110)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.hasNextChild(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:86)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:62)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask$PageRangeRender.render(RenderTask.java:661)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:284)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.renderReport(ReportEngineService.java:1545)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.getPage(BirtViewerReportService.java:204)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.doRenderPage(BirtChangeParameterActionHandler.java:82)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.__execute(AbstractChangeParameterActionHandler.java:103)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleChangeParameter(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:100)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Looks like a query error. Verify that it has the correct connection string and that the requested database server is available from where the report is being generated.

Comment: I have another report, with the exact same datasource, and is running fine from the server.

Comment: As mentionned this seems to be a query error, not a datasource error. There are many possible causes: a dataset parameter null in Tomcat context, a missing resource dependency, .... The datasource itself seems fine: "Unknown source" is not an error here, it is just pointing a missing debug information.  If the query is generated by a "beforeOpen" script, try to log the resulting queryText to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Just activated a log on beforeOpen, and shows no error at all. Just the sql query. BTW, I'm using BIRT viewer 2 on the server. Any chance of that causing the issue?